# Change reference name of listing

Tags: cross-referencing, listings, cleveref, ref

I would like to reference the listing like `Codebeispiel 1`. How can I do that? What I got is only `?? 1`

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage[nohyperlinks, printonlyused]{acronym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[driverfallback=hypertex]{hyperref} 
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\thechapter}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-10pt}{40pt}


\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}} % for vertical centering text in X column
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{position=bottom}


\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}%
  \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}}
\pagestyle{plain}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter. #1}{}}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\newcommand{\secref}[1]{\ref{#1} \nameref{#1}}

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{codegray}{gray}{0.9}
\newcommand{\code}[1]{\colorbox{codegray}{\texttt{#1}}}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[ngerman]{cleveref}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks   = true, %Colours links instead of ugly boxes
    urlcolor     = black, %Colour for external hyperlinks
    linkcolor    = black, %Colour of internal links
    citecolor   = black %Colour of citations
}


\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{xcolor}

%New colors defined below
\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray_s}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{HTML}{f5f5f5}

%Code listing style named "mystyle"
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour}, commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray_s},
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                    
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2
}

%"mystyle" code listing set
\lstset{style=mystyle}

\begin{document}
Hallo, dies ist etwas Text \cref{code}. Dieses Bild funktioniert \cref{fig:wetter_heatmap}

 \begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=10cm]{test.png}
    \caption{Bezeichnung der Abbildung}
    \label{fig:wetter_heatmap}
 \end{figure}
 
 
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python, caption=Python example, label=code]
import numpy as np
    
def incmatrix(genl1,genl2):
    m = len(genl1)
    n = len(genl2)
    M = None #to become the incidence matrix
    VT = np.zeros((n*m,1), int)  #dummy variable
    
    #compute the bitwise xor matrix
    M1 = bitxormatrix(genl1)
    M2 = np.triu(bitxormatrix(genl2),1) 

    for i in range(m-1):
        for j in range(i+1, m):
            [r,c] = np.where(M2 == M1[i,j])
            for k in range(len(r)):
                VT[(i)*n + r[k]] = 1;
                VT[(i)*n + c[k]] = 1;
                VT[(j)*n + r[k]] = 1;
                VT[(j)*n + c[k]] = 1;
                
                if M is None:
                    M = np.copy(VT)
                else:
                    M = np.concatenate((M, VT), 1)
                
                VT = np.zeros((n*m,1), int)
    
    return M
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load `cleveref` last, after `hyperref`.

[image: a]

If you want to change the "Listing"  use

```
\usepackage[ngerman]{cleveref}

\crefname{listing}{programmcode}{programmcode} 


\begin{document}
    Hallo, dies ist etwas Text \Cref{code}. Dieses Bild funktioniert \cref{fig:wetter_heatmap}
```

to get

[image: b]